# Indesign Javascript - Make an array from grep query

Tags: javascript, for-loop, adobe-indesign

I have a very long list of entries and I can select the individual entries I need via a GREP query but what I want to do is, each time a GREP query finds a match, I want it to add that selection to an array. The point being, that if I have all of the items from a particular search in an array I can then find the first instance of my query and put in a heading before any of the returned entries.

It might help to have an example of what I am exactly trying to achieve.
Below is an example of the list of information I have and you can see on the left is how the text is supplied. The words "***Subject Exhibition***" appear at the start of each entry. I want to remove the words from the start of each line and instead place one subhead before the first entry.

[Indesign text example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFkQx.jpg)

What I want help with is figuring out how should I structure the Javascript so that I can figure out what is the first instance of the Subject Exhibition entries.

I figure it will involve a for loop that each time it loops it will perform the grep find and add it to an array but I am not certain if that is the best way of tackling the problem?

Thanks

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, include codes in your question so we can point it out what is wrong and not

Comment: Hi @DoanVanThang I did have some code that was doing a portion of what I wanted but I was just stuck on getting access to the contents of the find results so I could pass that along to another query.
After some more investigation and trial and error I think I have actually figured it out and I will out it in below for reference if anyone else finds it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding a similar problem here: [JavaScript + InDesign: Find a word in a .indd document and write a .txt file with page number locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54187161/javascript-indesign-find-a-word-in-a-indd-document-and-write-a-txt-file-wit)
I took that code as a starting point and reworked it.

The first issue I had was that I didn't know how to access the contents of the find function. What InDesign returns from the Find is actually an Array of Text Objects (http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Array.html).

So the first step was to put the first result from the Find into a variable.

```
var found_txt = app.activeDocument.findGrep ()[0];
```

As mentioned above, the contents of the Array is a collection of Text Objects and that is all Indesign will return by accessing the first entry of the Array.
Next I had to convert the Text Object into a String so I had access to the actual contents of the found text. I got a tip-off from this post here
[How to store $2 value to variable in InDesign GREP find / change using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23458091/how-to-store-2-value-to-variable-in-indesign-grep-find-change-using-javascrip)

```
var firstResult = found_txt.contents;
```

By applying the .contents and putting it in a new variable I now have access to the String of text from the search result.
Below is the full code that performed the task I originally posted the question about. Hopefully it it might be useful to someone else.

```
main ();

function main() {
var grepQuery = "Subject Exhibition:.+$";

//Clear any existing Grep preferences
app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;

// set some options, add any that are needed
app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeLockedLayersForFind = true;
app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeLockedStoriesForFind = true;
app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeHiddenLayers = true;
app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeMasterPages = false;
app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeFootnotes = true;

//Put the search term into the query
app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = grepQuery;

//Put the first result of the find into a variable
var found_txt = app.activeDocument.findGrep ()[0];
//the find operation will return an Array of Text Objects.
//by using Javascripts CONTENTS it takes the reult and converts it into a regular String rather than a Text Object.
var firstResult = found_txt.contents;

//clear the preferences
app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;

//For the lookahead to work it needs something in front of it so I have told it to look for the return.
var newQuery = "\\r(?=" + firstResult + ")"
app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = newQuery;


//and add in the Section Header and Subject Exhibiton header above the found instance
app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo = "\\rSubject Exhibition\\r$0";
app.changeGrepPreferences.appliedParagraphStyle = "Award Header";

//Run the find\Change
app.activeDocument.changeGrep ();

//Clear Grep preferences
app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;    

alert("Finished");
return;
}
```